Odoo 17 module not showing in the app list after installing
I'm installing GYM management Module on Odoo 17 Enterprise locally
the 16 version of the same module is working on Odoo 16 with no errors
The module is installed successfully but the app is not showing in the app list.
I tried updating the app list and restarting the server but nothing changes.
the Terminal shows this :
2024-05-23 08:11:38,705 853 INFO IRAM_GH_DB odoo.addons.base.models.ir_module: ALLOW access to module.button_immediate_install on ['GYM Management System'] to user info@grandhoteltartous.com #2 via 192.168.101.108
2024-05-23 08:11:38,705 853 INFO IRAM_GH_DB odoo.addons.base.models.ir_module: User #2 triggered module installation
2024-05-23 08:11:38,706 853 INFO IRAM_GH_DB odoo.addons.base.models.ir_module: ALLOW access to module.button_install on ['GYM Management System'] to user info@grandhoteltartous.com #2 via 192.168.101.108
2024-05-23 08:11:38,781 853 INFO IRAM_GH_DB odoo.modules.loading: loading 1 modules...
2024-05-23 08:11:38,787 853 INFO IRAM_GH_DB odoo.modules.loading: 1 modules loaded in 0.01s, 0 queries (+0 extra)
2024-05-23 08:11:38,804 853 INFO IRAM_GH_DB odoo.modules.loading: updating modules list
2024-05-23 08:11:38,805 853 INFO IRAM_GH_DB odoo.addons.base.models.ir_module: ALLOW access to module.update_list on [] to user __system__ #1 via 192.168.101.108
2024-05-23 08:11:39,434 853 WARNING IRAM_GH_DB odoo.modules.graph: module hr_grade_rank: not installable, skipped
2024-05-23 08:11:39,435 853 WARNING IRAM_GH_DB odoo.modules.graph: module salon_management: not installable, skipped
2024-05-23 08:11:39,454 853 INFO IRAM_GH_DB odoo.modules.loading: loading 354 modules...
2024-05-23 08:11:39,587 853 INFO IRAM_GH_DB odoo.modules.loading: 354 modules loaded in 0.13s, 0 queries (+0 extra)
2024-05-23 08:11:39,592 853 INFO IRAM_GH_DB odoo.modules.loading: loading 355 modules...
2024-05-23 08:11:39,593 853 INFO IRAM_GH_DB odoo.modules.loading: Loading module gym_mgmt_system (298/355)
2024-05-23 08:11:39,831 853 WARNING IRAM_GH_DB odoo.fields: Field workout.plan.option.equipment_id: unknown parameter 'tracking', if this is an actual parameter you may want to override the method _valid_field_parameter on the relevant model in order to allow it
2024-05-23 08:11:39,897 853 INFO IRAM_GH_DB odoo.modules.registry: module gym_mgmt_system: creating or updating database tables
2024-05-23 08:11:40,719 853 ERROR IRAM_GH_DB odoo.schema: Table 'gym_membership': unable to add constraint 'gym_membership_membership_date_greater' as check(membership_date_to >= membership_date_from)
2024-05-23 08:11:42,405 853 WARNING IRAM_GH_DB odoo.addons.base.models.ir_model: Two fields (note_step, note_benefit) of gym.exercise() have the same label: Note. [Modules: gym_mgmt_system and gym_mgmt_system]
2024-05-23 08:11:42,405 853 WARNING IRAM_GH_DB odoo.addons.base.models.ir_model: Two fields (image, image_1920) of gym.exercise() have the same label: Image. [Modules: gym_mgmt_system and base]
2024-05-23 08:11:42,405 853 WARNING IRAM_GH_DB odoo.addons.base.models.ir_model: Two fields (image12, image_1920) of gym.exercise() have the same label: Image. [Modules: gym_mgmt_system and base]
2024-05-23 08:11:42,405 853 WARNING IRAM_GH_DB odoo.addons.base.models.ir_model: Two fields (image123, image_1920) of gym.exercise() have the same label: Image. [Modules: gym_mgmt_system and base]
2024-05-23 08:11:42,405 853 WARNING IRAM_GH_DB odoo.addons.base.models.ir_model: Two fields (image124, image_1920) of gym.exercise() have the same label: Image. [Modules: gym_mgmt_system and base]
2024-05-23 08:11:42,491 853 ERROR IRAM_GH_DB odoo.schema: Table 'product_template': unable to set NOT NULL on column 'sh_max_allow_person'
2024-05-23 08:11:42,783 853 INFO IRAM_GH_DB odoo.modules.loading: loading gym_mgmt_system/security/gym_mgmt_system_groups.xml
2024-05-23 08:11:42,831 853 INFO IRAM_GH_DB odoo.modules.loading: loading gym_mgmt_system/security/ir.model.access.csv
2024-05-23 08:11:42,853 853 ERROR IRAM_GH_DB odoo.sql_db: bad query:
            INSERT INTO ir_model_data (module,name,model,res_id,noupdate)
            VALUES ('gym_mgmt_system','access_assign_workout','ir.model.access',2527,false), ('gym_mgmt_system','access_assign_workout','ir.model.access',2528,false), ('gym_mgmt_system','access_assign_workout_operator','ir.model.access',2529,false), ('gym_mgmt_system','access_hr_employee_trainer','ir.model.access',2530,false), ('gym_mgmt_system','access_hr_employee_member','ir.model.access',2531,false), ('gym_mgmt_system','access_hr_employee_operator','ir.model.access',2532,false), ('gym_mgmt_system','access_sale_order_trainer','ir.model.access',2533,false), ('gym_mgmt_system','access_sale_order_member','ir.model.access',2534,false), ('gym_mgmt_system','access_sale_order_operator','ir.model.access',2535,false), ('gym_mgmt_system','access_product_template_trainer','ir.model.access',2536,false), ('gym_mgmt_system','access_product_template_member','ir.model.access',2537,false), ('gym_mgmt_system','access_product_template_operator','ir.model.access',2538,false), ('gym_mgmt_system','access_res_partner_trainer','ir.model.access',2539,false), ('gym_mgmt_system','access_res_partner_operator','ir.model.access',2540,false), ('gym_mgmt_system','access_res_partner_member','ir.model.access',2541,false), ('gym_mgmt_system','access_gym_membership_operator','ir.model.access',2542,false), ('gym_mgmt_system','access_gym_membership_trainer','ir.model.access',2543,false), ('gym_mgmt_system','access_gym_membership_member','ir.model.access',2544,false), ('gym_mgmt_system','access_measurement_history_operator','ir.model.access',2545,false), ('gym_mgmt_system','access_measurement_history_trainer','ir.model.access',2546,false), ('gym_mgmt_system','access_measurement_history_member','ir.model.access',2547,false), ('gym_mgmt_system','access_trainer_skill_operator','ir.model.access',2548,false), ('gym_mgmt_system','access_trainer_skill_member','ir.model.access',2549,false), ('gym_mgmt_system','access_trainer_skill_trainer','ir.model.access',2550,false), ('gym_mgmt_system','access_product_template_trainer','ir.model.access',2551,false), ('gym_mgmt_system','access_product_template_member','ir.model.access',2552,false), ('gym_mgmt_system','access_product_template_operator','ir.model.access',2553,false), ('gym_mgmt_system','access_workout_plan_operator','ir.model.access',2554,false), ('gym_mgmt_system','access_workout_plan_trainer','ir.model.access',2555,false), ('gym_mgmt_system','access_workout_plan_member','ir.model.access',2556,false), ('gym_mgmt_system','access_workout_plan_option_operator','ir.model.access',2557,false), ('gym_mgmt_system','access_workout_plan_option_trainer','ir.model.access',2558,false), ('gym_mgmt_system','access_workout_plan_option_member','ir.model.access',2559,false), ('gym_mgmt_system','access_workout_days_operator','ir.model.access',2560,false), ('gym_mgmt_system','access_workout_days_trainer','ir.model.access',2561,false), ('gym_mgmt_system','access_workout_days_member','ir.model.access',2562,false), ('gym_mgmt_system','access_gym_exercise_operator','ir.model.access',2563,false), ('gym_mgmt_system','access_gym_exercise_trainer','ir.model.access',2564,false), ('gym_mgmt_system','access_gym_exercise_member','ir.model.access',2565,false), ('gym_mgmt_system','access_exercise_for_operator','ir.model.access',2566,false), ('gym_mgmt_system','access_exercise_for_trainer','ir.model.access',2567,false), ('gym_mgmt_system','access_exercise_for_member','ir.model.access',2568,false), ('gym_mgmt_system','access_trainer_skill_operator','ir.model.access',2569,false), ('gym_mgmt_system','access_trainer_skill_trainer','ir.model.access',2570,false), ('gym_mgmt_system','access_trainer_skill_member','ir.model.access',2571,false), ('gym_mgmt_system','access_my_workout_plan_operator','ir.model.access',2572,false), ('gym_mgmt_system','access_my_workout_plan_trainer','ir.model.access',2573,false), ('gym_mgmt_system','access_my_workout_plan_member','ir.model.access',2574,false)
            ON CONFLICT (module, name)
            DO UPDATE SET (model, res_id, write_date) =
                (EXCLUDED.model, EXCLUDED.res_id, now() at time zone 'UTC')
                WHERE (ir_model_data.res_id != EXCLUDED.res_id OR ir_model_data.model != EXCLUDED.model)
            RETURNING module, name, model, res_id, create_date, write_date

ERROR: ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE command cannot affect row a second time
HINT:  Ensure that no rows proposed for insertion within the same command have duplicate constrained values.

2024-05-23 08:11:42,853 853 ERROR IRAM_GH_DB odoo.addons.base.models.ir_model: Failed to insert ir_model_data
('gym_mgmt_system', 'access_assign_workout', 'ir.model.access', 2527, False)
('gym_mgmt_system', 'access_assign_workout', 'ir.model.access', 2528, False)
('gym_mgmt_system', 'access_assign_workout_operator', 'ir.model.access', 2529, False)
('gym_mgmt_system', 'access_hr_employee_trainer', 'ir.model.access', 2530, False)
('gym_mgmt_system', 'access_hr_employee_member', 'ir.model.access', 2531, False)
('gym_mgmt_system', 'access_hr_employee_operator', 'ir.model.access', 2532, False)
('gym_mgmt_system', 'access_sale_order_trainer', 'ir.model.access', 2533, False)
('gym_mgmt_system', 'access_sale_order_member', 'ir.model.access', 2534, False)
('gym_mgmt_system', 'access_sale_order_operator', 'ir.model.access', 2535, False)
('gym_mgmt_system', 'access_product_template_trainer', 'ir.model.access', 2536, False)
('gym_mgmt_system', 'access_product_template_member', 'ir.model.access', 2537, False)
('gym_mgmt_system', 'access_product_template_operator', 'ir.model.access', 2538, False)
('gym_mgmt_system', 'access_res_partner_trainer', 'ir.model.access', 2539, False)
('gym_mgmt_system', 'access_res_partner_operator', 'ir.model.access', 2540, False)
('gym_mgmt_system', 'access_res_partner_member', 'ir.model.access', 2541, False)
('gym_mgmt_system', 'access_gym_membership_operator', 'ir.model.access', 2542, False)
('gym_mgmt_system', 'access_gym_membership_trainer', 'ir.model.access', 2543, False)
('gym_mgmt_system', 'access_gym_membership_member', 'ir.model.access', 2544, False)
('gym_mgmt_system', 'access_measurement_history_operator', 'ir.model.access', 2545, False)
('gym_mgmt_system', 'access_measurement_history_trainer', 'ir.model.access', 2546, False)
('gym_mgmt_system', 'access_measurement_history_member', 'ir.model.access', 2547, False)
('gym_mgmt_system', 'access_trainer_skill_operator', 'ir.model.access', 2548, False)
('gym_mgmt_system', 'access_trainer_skill_member', 'ir.model.access', 2549, False)
('gym_mgmt_system', 'access_trainer_skill_trainer', 'ir.model.access', 2550, False)
('gym_mgmt_system', 'access_product_template_trainer', 'ir.model.access', 2551, False)
('gym_mgmt_system', 'access_product_template_member', 'ir.model.access', 2552, False)
('gym_mgmt_system', 'access_product_template_operator', 'ir.model.access', 2553, False)
('gym_mgmt_system', 'access_workout_plan_operator', 'ir.model.access', 2554, False)
('gym_mgmt_system', 'access_workout_plan_trainer', 'ir.model.access', 2555, False)
('gym_mgmt_system', 'access_workout_plan_member', 'ir.model.access', 2556, False)
('gym_mgmt_system', 'access_workout_plan_option_operator', 'ir.model.access', 2557, False)
('gym_mgmt_system', 'access_workout_plan_option_trainer', 'ir.model.access', 2558, False)
('gym_mgmt_system', 'access_workout_plan_option_member', 'ir.model.access', 2559, False)
('gym_mgmt_system', 'access_workout_days_operator', 'ir.model.access', 2560, False)
('gym_mgmt_system', 'access_workout_days_trainer', 'ir.model.access', 2561, False)
('gym_mgmt_system', 'access_workout_days_member', 'ir.model.access', 2562, False)
('gym_mgmt_system', 'access_gym_exercise_operator', 'ir.model.access', 2563, False)
('gym_mgmt_system', 'access_gym_exercise_trainer', 'ir.model.access', 2564, False)
('gym_mgmt_system', 'access_gym_exercise_member', 'ir.model.access', 2565, False)
('gym_mgmt_system', 'access_exercise_for_operator', 'ir.model.access', 2566, False)
('gym_mgmt_system', 'access_exercise_for_trainer', 'ir.model.access', 2567, False)
('gym_mgmt_system', 'access_exercise_for_member', 'ir.model.access', 2568, False)
('gym_mgmt_system', 'access_trainer_skill_operator', 'ir.model.access', 2569, False)
('gym_mgmt_system', 'access_trainer_skill_trainer', 'ir.model.access', 2570, False)
('gym_mgmt_system', 'access_trainer_skill_member', 'ir.model.access', 2571, False)
('gym_mgmt_system', 'access_my_workout_plan_operator', 'ir.model.access', 2572, False)
('gym_mgmt_system', 'access_my_workout_plan_trainer', 'ir.model.access', 2573, False)
('gym_mgmt_system', 'access_my_workout_plan_member', 'ir.model.access', 2574, False)
2024-05-23 08:11:42,915 853 INFO IRAM_GH_DB odoo.modules.loading: loading gym_mgmt_system/security/gym_mgmt_system_security.xml
2024-05-23 08:11:42,935 853 INFO IRAM_GH_DB odoo.modules.loading: loading gym_mgmt_system/data/ir_sequence_data.xml
2024-05-23 08:11:42,939 853 INFO IRAM_GH_DB odoo.modules.loading: loading gym_mgmt_system/wizard/assign_workout.xml
2024-05-23 08:11:42,947 853 INFO IRAM_GH_DB odoo.modules.loading: loading gym_mgmt_system/views/product_template_views.xml
2024-05-23 08:11:42,978 853 INFO IRAM_GH_DB odoo.modules.loading: loading gym_mgmt_system/views/res_partner_views.xml
2024-05-23 08:11:43,014 853 INFO IRAM_GH_DB odoo.modules.loading: loading gym_mgmt_system/views/exercise_for_views.xml
2024-05-23 08:11:43,024 853 INFO IRAM_GH_DB odoo.modules.loading: loading gym_mgmt_system/views/gym_exercise_views.xml
2024-05-23 08:11:43,034 853 INFO IRAM_GH_DB odoo.modules.loading: loading gym_mgmt_system/views/gym_membership_views.xml
2024-05-23 08:11:43,047 853 INFO IRAM_GH_DB odoo.modules.loading: loading gym_mgmt_system/views/measurement_history_views.xml
2024-05-23 08:11:43,060 853 INFO IRAM_GH_DB odoo.modules.loading: loading gym_mgmt_system/views/membership_plan_views.xml
2024-05-23 08:11:43,067 853 INFO IRAM_GH_DB odoo.modules.loading: loading gym_mgmt_system/views/gym_report_views.xml
2024-05-23 08:11:43,083 853 INFO IRAM_GH_DB odoo.modules.loading: loading gym_mgmt_system/views/trainer_skill_views.xml
2024-05-23 08:11:43,090 853 INFO IRAM_GH_DB odoo.modules.loading: loading gym_mgmt_system/views/workout_plan_views.xml
2024-05-23 08:11:43,106 853 INFO IRAM_GH_DB odoo.modules.loading: loading gym_mgmt_system/views/workout_days_views.xml
2024-05-23 08:11:43,115 853 INFO IRAM_GH_DB odoo.modules.loading: loading gym_mgmt_system/views/my_workout_plan_views.xml
2024-05-23 08:11:43,128 853 INFO IRAM_GH_DB odoo.modules.loading: loading gym_mgmt_system/views/hr_employee_views.xml
2024-05-23 08:11:43,209 853 WARNING IRAM_GH_DB odoo.modules.loading: The models ['gym.report'] have no access rules in module gym_mgmt_system, consider adding some, like:
id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink


Have you probably just forgotten to give your user the app's rights?

I have solved the problem by the following steps:
settings ——> Users & companies —-> users ——> Please just choose admin —-> search Gym management ——> selection operator

The same id (access_assign_workout) is used for two groups and there are duplicates in the CSV file like access_product_template_member, you need to remove them.
It will try to add SQL constraints  (check) on related fields, just comment it and use a python constraint
Try the following CSV file:
id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
access_assign_workout_trainer,access.assign.workout,model_assign_workout,gym_mgmt_system.group_gym_trainer,1,0,0,0
access_assign_workout_member,access.assign.workout,model_assign_workout,gym_mgmt_system.group_gym_member,1,0,0,0
access_assign_workout_operator,access.assign.workout,model_assign_workout,gym_mgmt_system.group_gym_operator,1,1,1,1
access_hr_employee_trainer,access.hr.employee,model_hr_employee,gym_mgmt_system.group_gym_trainer,1,1,1,0
access_hr_employee_member,access.hr.employee,model_hr_employee,gym_mgmt_system.group_gym_member,1,0,0,0
access_hr_employee_operator,access.hr.employee,model_hr_employee,gym_mgmt_system.group_gym_operator,1,1,1,1
access_sale_order_trainer,access.sale.order,model_sale_order,gym_mgmt_system.group_gym_trainer,1,1,1,0
access_sale_order_member,access.sale.order,model_sale_order,gym_mgmt_system.group_gym_member,1,0,0,0
access_sale_order_operator,access.sale.order,model_sale_order,gym_mgmt_system.group_gym_operator,1,1,1,1
access_product_template_trainer,access.product.template,model_product_template,gym_mgmt_system.group_gym_trainer,1,1,1,0
access_product_template_member,access.product.template,model_product_template,gym_mgmt_system.group_gym_member,1,0,0,0
access_product_template_operator,access.product.template,model_product_template,gym_mgmt_system.group_gym_operator,1,1,1,1
access_res_partner_trainer,access.res.partner,model_res_partner,gym_mgmt_system.group_gym_trainer,1,0,0,0
access_res_partner_operator,access.res.partner,model_res_partner,gym_mgmt_system.group_gym_operator,1,1,1,1
access_res_partner_member,access.res.partner,model_res_partner,gym_mgmt_system.group_gym_member,1,0,0,0
access_gym_membership_operator,access.gym.membership,model_gym_membership,gym_mgmt_system.group_gym_operator,1,1,1,1
access_gym_membership_trainer,access.gym.membership,model_gym_membership,gym_mgmt_system.group_gym_trainer,1,0,0,0
access_gym_membership_member,access.gym.membership,model_gym_membership,gym_mgmt_system.group_gym_member,1,0,0,0
access_measurement_history_operator,access.measurement.history,model_measurement_history,gym_mgmt_system.group_gym_operator,1,1,1,1
access_measurement_history_trainer,access.measurement.history,model_measurement_history,gym_mgmt_system.group_gym_trainer,1,1,1,1
access_measurement_history_member,access.measurement.history,model_measurement_history,gym_mgmt_system.group_gym_member,1,0,0,0
access_trainer_skill_operator,access.trainer_skill,model_trainer_skill,gym_mgmt_system.group_gym_operator,1,1,1,1
access_trainer_skill_member,access.trainer_skill,model_trainer_skill,gym_mgmt_system.group_gym_member,1,0,0,0
access_trainer_skill_trainer,access.trainer_skill,model_trainer_skill,gym_mgmt_system.group_gym_trainer,1,1,1,1
access_workout_plan_operator,access.workout.plan,model_workout_plan,gym_mgmt_system.group_gym_operator,1,1,1,1
access_workout_plan_trainer,access.workout.plan,model_workout_plan,gym_mgmt_system.group_gym_trainer,1,1,1,1
access_workout_plan_member,access.workout.plan,model_workout_plan,gym_mgmt_system.group_gym_member,1,0,0,0
access_workout_plan_option_operator,access.workout.plan.option,model_workout_plan_option,gym_mgmt_system.group_gym_operator,1,1,1,1
access_workout_plan_option_trainer,access.workout.plan.option,model_workout_plan_option,gym_mgmt_system.group_gym_trainer,1,1,1,1
access_workout_plan_option_member,access.workout.plan.option,model_workout_plan_option,gym_mgmt_system.group_gym_member,1,0,0,0
access_workout_days_operator,access.workout.days,model_workout_days,gym_mgmt_system.group_gym_operator,1,1,1,1
access_workout_days_trainer,access.workout.days,model_workout_days,gym_mgmt_system.group_gym_trainer,1,1,1,1
access_workout_days_member,access.workout.days,model_workout_days,gym_mgmt_system.group_gym_member,1,1,0,0
access_gym_exercise_operator,access.gym.exercise,model_gym_exercise,gym_mgmt_system.group_gym_operator,1,1,1,1
access_gym_exercise_trainer,access.gym.exercise,model_gym_exercise,gym_mgmt_system.group_gym_trainer,1,1,1,1
access_gym_exercise_member,access.gym.exercise,model_gym_exercise,gym_mgmt_system.group_gym_member,1,0,0,
access_exercise_for_operator,access.exercise.for,model_exercise_for,gym_mgmt_system.group_gym_operator,1,1,1,1
access_exercise_for_trainer,access.exercise.for,model_exercise_for,gym_mgmt_system.group_gym_trainer,1,1,1,1
access_exercise_for_member,access.exercise.for,model_exercise_for,gym_mgmt_system.group_gym_member,1,0,0,0
access_my_workout_plan_operator,access.my.workout.plan,model_my_workout_plan,gym_mgmt_system.group_gym_operator,1,1,1,1
access_my_workout_plan_trainer,access.my.workout.plan,model_my_workout_plan,gym_mgmt_system.group_gym_trainer,1,1,1,1
access_my_workout_plan_member,access.my.workout.plan,model_my_workout_plan,gym_mgmt_system.group_gym_member,1,0,0,0

You will need to set the "Gym Management" group in the user form

Sometimes i should read the real info, then i would've seen there is an error in the log. I was fooled by "The module is installed successfully"... Good answer!

I modified the CSV file but the module still not appearing.
I talked to Cybrosys and they asked for a whopping 1000$ to fix their buggy module.
